# ISO file path not an option when installing Linux on virtualbox

Tags: linux, installation, virtualbox

When installing Linux on a virtualbox with a windows 7 64bit host

I get the following screen [image]

All the tutorials I have watched on how to install Linux on a virtualbox always skip this screen

I am using a iso file but I do not see an option to enter the path of said iso file

do I need to copy the file to a cd? or am I missing a setting for the virtualbox?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way VirtualBox (or virtualization in general) works, is that when on the host (the Windows PC running the VirtualBox) you mount the ISO file as a CD/DVD drive,  it will be shown as CD/DVD on the client (your Linux installation). The client won't see the difference.

So in that sense you are doing it correctly. However, you have the "wrong" installation ISO. The file you have mounted is "Oracle Linux R6 Update 5 UEK Boot ISO x86_64 V41364-01.iso" (if I googled correctly). So the question in your first screenshot asking about the installation image is to my understanding asking for where the actual installation data can be found. This would be either a DVD, another harddrive, local repository in LAN, or from the Internet. In your case it would be easier to use an installation media, which already includes the installation files, which would be "Oracle Linux R6 Update 5 x86_64 V41362-01.iso" (again if I googled correctly).

So to sum up, either download the full installation image (around 4 GB), or use the one you have and point the "url" to an image from the Internet.